# iPhone/iPad touch event to trigger different div

Tags: events, ipad, touch, target

Seems like an easy solution but I can't wrap my head around it. I have four divs like the one below

```
<div ontouchstart="touchStart(event)" ontouchmove="touchMove (event)" ontouchend="touchEnd (event)" class="c1" id="c1">copy1</div>
```

The code for touchStart is very simple at the moment:

```
function touchStart (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.target.style.color="#ff0000";
    return false;
}
```

The issue is how can the touch functions target a different div (not the target that was touched) and change it's opacity from 0 to 1 in touchStart, then from 1 to 0 in touchEnd.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert but here's my two cents and hopefully will help you find a solution

With jquery, clicking one element can trigger a different one and change the target's css opacity attribute like:

```
$("#div_thats_touched").click(function(){
        $("#target_div").css("opacity","1");
    })
```

in javascript it would be something like

```
this.onClick(function(){
target=document.getElementById('target');
target.style.opacity("1");
});
```

or if you want to trigger the event of another element:

```
$("#div_thats_touched").click(function(){
            $("#target_div").trigger("click");
        })
```

And instead of having touchstart and touchend, you could use jquery's toggle method to combine them into one method (maybe) 
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/